How to draw a lifecycle phase diagram?
This sort of diagram looks very similar to a donut type of diagram but each segment is an arrow to display a model.
Here is one I could produce as SVG using an LLM prompt. Looks like a Picasso inspiration.
Is there a way to create such diagrams dynamically in Matplotlib or another diagramming software for X arcs of given lengths? i.e. as donut chart decoration.

